# Is clearing a vector considered a proper way of managing memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I tried to make the question title as descriptive as possible so you won't have to click on the question to figure out whether you have an answer for my question.

I am implementing a `chaining hash table` for a class assignment, and I have come to the conclusion that a `vector` would best serve the purpose of my project.

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
struct node
{
public:
    node(string key, node * next = NULL)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->next = next;
    }

    string key;
    node * next;
};

class htable
{
private:
    static const int TABLE_SIZE = 100;
    vector <node*> table;


public:
    htable()
    {
        table.resize(TABLE_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            table[i] = NULL;
    }

    ~htable()
    {
        table.erase(table.begin(), table.begin() + TABLE_SIZE);
    }

};
```

Will the `erase` function in my `htable` class `destructor` perform proper memory management?

Comment: Why does you design `node` for linked list but implement with `vector`?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the erase function in my htable class destructor perform proper memory management?

No.  Your `vector<node*>` doesn't use smart pointers, so it does nothing to call destructors nor release memory for the objects in the data structure.

Doing a `delete` on each `node*` (or use smart pointers) is a good first step, but that wouldn't be enough because the `node` destructor doesn't invoke the destructor(s) for linked `node`s.

There's no need to call `erase` - the `vector` automatically invokes any destructors for the elements it contains when the `htable` object destructor runs - the problem is that `node*` elements don't trigger any destruction actions, so you need that explicit loop calling `delete` or to use smart pointers.

Separately, you have a hash set rather than a map... there're only `key`s.

Perhaps you should try:

```
std:vector<std::list<std::string>>
```

This will take care of the data cleanup automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do barely any manual memory management at all, you need to clarify the ownership of the elements of your hash table. Using a `std::vector` is a good idea, but you need to also decide whether your chains are going to be doubly linked or singly linked. If They're singly linked, it's better to have a vector of unique pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> table;
```

Otherwise you want shared ownership:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>> table;
```

Also note that you're not using the constructor correctly. You need to take advantage of the initializer list in the constructor: you can simply make your vector to be the size `TABLE_SIZE` by invoking the appropriate vector constructor in the initializer list, like so:

```
htable():table(TABLE_SIZE, std::make_shared<node>(nullptr)){}
```

Though if you have no access to a C++11 compiler the above advice is moot, except for utilizing the initializer list in your constructor.